# 11.10 wubi not able to access windows drives

Tags: 11.10, windows, wubi

Earlier have installed ubuntu 11.04 using wubi and from my ubuntu, I was able to access my windows drives (Places>...)

Now I have upgraded to 11.10 and now I am not able to access the same

Any thoughts...

Thanks in advance
Siva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cairo-dock its possible. have tested and it worked